# How do I change $('input[type=text]') to plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

**$('input[type=text]')**

How do I convert this to plain javascript

I've been trying to figure this out but no luck

Comment: there is jquery to js converters online (`document.querySelector('input[type=text]')`)

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');`

Comment: `$('input[type=text]')` returns a jQuery object, so there is no plain JavaScript variant if you want to avoid using jQuery. You'll need to provide more context about what you do with the result of this expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
const el = document.querySelector("input[type='text']");
```

Comment: This returns an Element and not a jQuery object like `$('input[type=text]')` does. You can't use `document.querySelector("input[type='text']").val('New value')` like you can use `$('input[type=text]').val('New value')`.

Comment: Of course, not, because it is not a jQuery=). You can't mix both approaches in this example. Author asked: how to convert this piece of code to PLAIN js. That's all. Did you read the question? The question was not about working with jQuery objects in JS. Of course, JS method doesnt returns jQuery object - it's obvious thing. And if author wants to exctract value from my example using vanilla JS, he should write: `const value = document.querySelector("input[type='text']").value;`.Or if he wants to redefine value: `const el = document.querySelector("input[type='text']"); el.value = 'New value';`

Comment: Agree with the general principle: answer can't be expected to return a jQuery object. The only answer would be "continue to use $", if the goal was to get a jQuery object. That being said, `querySelectorAll` is closer to what `$` does. It returns an array of matching elements, not just one. As `$` does.

Comment: My point is that the question can't be answered. OP seems to looking for a replacement where they can just find and replace any `$(...)` in the code, and this isn't going to work. It might be obvious to _you_ that this returns something different, but OP clearly isn't a seasoned JavaScript/jQuery programmer. They need to provide more context in order to adequately answer their question. (Or the answer should highlight the difference.)

Comment: Considered from this point of view, I fully agree with yours comments above

Answer (score -1):

You can try this,

```
[...document.getElementsByTagName("input")].filter(d => d.type === 'text')
```